# How to trigger Bamboo build on a release build of another plan

Tags: jenkins, bamboo

I have a Parent plan on which Child1 and Child2 plans depends on.

When Parent Plan builds I DON'T want the Child1 and Child2 triggered.

However I would like the Child1 and Child2 plans to build when the Parent Plan performs a Release build.

In Jenkins we use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to achieve the same.

Wondering what avenues do Bamboo have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bamboo, your Release Build of the parent would be a **plan**. You wouldn't usually have a plan that could represent a development build and a release build.

**Example structure;**

Some **Project**:

- Parent Dev **Plan** (e.g. builds on every SCM commit)
- Parent Release **Plan** (e.g. build manually for release)
- Child A Plan
- Child B Plan

In the `Parent Release Plan` you can the configure **Dependencies** where you select your two Child Plans. This will then trigger the build of each child plan when the Parent Release Plan is successfully built.

You could separate the child plans into a different project if desired.